# Ease transition between images in JavaScript slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, slideshow

I'm using JavaScript to randomly display an array of images with timed intervals.

This is the script:

```
var NumberOfImages = 5

var img = new Array(NumberOfImages)

    img[0] = "[image here]"
    img[1] = "[image here]"
    img[2] = "[image here]"
    img[3] = "[image here]"
    img[4] = "[image here]"

Array.prototype.shuffle = function () {
    var len = this.length;
    var i = len;
    while (i--) {
        var p = parseInt(Math.random()*len);
        var t = this[i];
    this[i] = this[p];
    this[p] = t;
    }
};

img.shuffle ();

var imgNumber = 0

function NextImage() {
    document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber++]

        if (imgNumber == img.length) {
               img.shuffle ();
               imgNumber = 0;
        }
}

window.setInterval (NextImage, 3000);
```

and the html:

```
<div class="item">
    <script type="text/javascript">document.writeln('<img src="'+img[0]+'" name="VCRImage">');</script>
</div>
```

A working example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/admiringtheorchid/esm3u0xg/

I would like to ease the transition between each image. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: There are lots and lots of resources easily found on the web to give you ideas how to do this. You are expected to have at least done some basic research before asking questions here

Comment: I should add that I'd done hours of research before posting my question to the forum. Indeed I found many solutions but none that I was able to implement successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/qxf69hsL/

```
//create a jQuery object of the image
    var $image = $(document.images["VCRImage"]);

//fade out the image, and once it has finished fading out... 
    $image.fadeOut(function() {  

//change the image source
        $image.attr("src", img[imgNumber++]);                    
    });

//fade the image back in
    $image.fadeIn();
```

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of your proposal, however, your jsfiddle doesn't seem to work. Should I add your code to the function 'NextImage', replace it or include it beneath?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to update my jsfiddle, see now @DBenway

Comment: Thanks @joe_young. This nearly works but the first image in the array is repeated. I can’t figure out why.

Comment: Okay I've fixed that bit in my fiddle, if that's not the desired behaviour do tell me @DBenway

Comment: Problem solved @joe_young though a new one has arisen. If I leave the page open in a tab and work on something else for a while, when I come back, a single image is loaded over and over again. Also, sometimes the loading of an image is visible as it fades in. How can this be prevented for a seamless transition?